# Get unique set of string values from a query

Tags: apex, soql, list, loop, set

I have a custom object called Asset__c in which there is a lookup field called Site__c which is linked to another custom object called Site__c.

This Assets object has more that 20k records. What i want is Set of string values which has unique site names. I tried grouped query but it didn't work and there was a limit issue.

What i did is, i queried all the records and looped through them and added the Site__r.Name field to a new set. Similar to Site__r.Name i also want to get the set of unique values for few other fields as well.

Is there a more efficient way to do it. please help.  below is the sample code.

```
Set<String> sitelist = new Set<String>();
Set<String> customerlist = new Set<String>();
for(Asset__c ast:[Select Id,Site__r.name, customer_Name__c from Asset__c]) {
sitelist.add(ast.Site__r.name);
customerlist.add(ast.customer_Name__c);
}
```

Actual query used

```
SELECT Dealer__r.Name FROM Asset__c WHERE ACM_Service_Level__c IN ('Service Level 2','Service Level 1') AND ECM_Enabled__c = true AND RecordType.Name = 'Machine' group by Dealer__r.Name
```

Comment: 20000 recs should be well within Aggregate query capabilities;

Comment: Do you actually need the other fields in the query or can you just use: SELECT Site__r.name FROM Asset__c GROUP BY Site__r.name

Comment: @BrandonWind I need other fields as well.

Comment: @cropredy i got an error with aggregate query.
System.QueryException: Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch

Comment: Exactly how many Asset__c? And use [edit] to show exact Aggregate query

Comment: there a re total of 20132 assets that meets the query criteria.
I have the actual query to the post.

Comment: The documentation says you need to work with more precise queries when using group by https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_group_by_considerations.htm. So to answer your question on the salesforce platform no there is not a better way to do this.